# Angular 5 HttpClient post send token in wrong format?

Tags: angular, token, httpclient

I have back-end on Java and front on Angular 5. So my problem in use HttpClient. When i send post request with token, like:

```
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', token);
    this.http.post(url, data, {headers: headers})
         .map((response: Response) => response.json());
```

i am always had - 401 Error (Unauthorized), but when i send this request by curl:

```
     curl -s -X POST --header 'Authorization: sometoken' -d '{"text": 
     "somedata"}' 'http://someurl'
```

all is ok! May be someone meet same problems?

NEW! May be it can help, in Network section of Chromium i see next information about this request:

```
Request headers: 
Accept: / Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate 
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type 
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: It's usually [`Authorization: Bearer <token>`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#page-5)

Comment: If he's getting a different result with curl, I would not assume that the Bearer string is missing.

Comment: i try send token in that format: ( 'Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token) but had same result :(